# What is wrong with this Matlab code? Simple While Loop

Tags: matlab

Totally new at MatLab and I need it to answer this homework question for my class. I'm trying to see when this equation (mu) will equal a certain value (sae30mu) while decreasing x so that I can find the correct value for x. However, when it prints x, I get a negative number. I cannot tell why this code won't work, as it appears (to me) that it should just spit out the answer.

```
  x = 1.0;
   mu = ((sae10mu)^x)*((sae50mu)^(1-x));

   while (mu ~= sae30mu & x >= 0)
       x = x - 0.01;
       mu = ((sae10mu)^x)*((sae50mu)^(1-x));
   end

   x
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems here.

Firstly, you aren't getting the right answer because `mu` will never equal `sae10mu`, so `mu~=sae10mu` will always be true. Limits of numerical precision mean that you can't do floating point comparison like this. Instead, you need to define some tolerance, `tol`, and do a comparison like `abs(mu-sae10mu)>tol`. Then, once `mu` is within `tol` of `sae10mu`, the condition will be true.

Secondly, the `x>=0` will be true until `x` is less than 0. The first value you will get to is the largest value of `x` less than 0, which is -0.01. To stop at `x=0`, do `x>0`.

Your `while` loop should look like this: `while(abs(mu-sae10mu)>tol & x>0)`.

Comment: Technically it should also use `&&` instead of just `&` as well